# Interactive trigger for external image viewer?

Tags: qgis, image, display, tracking, viewer

Is it possible to navigate from point to point with a shortcut on the keyboard and interactively (tracking) display the embedded photos at the point locations in an external image viewer?

I could do so with the ACTION option, but I must navigate from point to point with the mouse pointer.

Is any tool available in QGIS or any python code capable of such thing?

Comment: There's an old (now deprecated, incompatible with QGIS3) plugin called Feature Iterator that would pan from one feature to the next at the click of a button. If you were interested in developing your own plugin, Feature Iterator might be useful as a model.

Comment: Otherwise the closest method I know of would be setting up an Atlas in the print layout, and add an image where the image filepath is controlled by the atlas.

Comment: Also have a look at the Go2NextFeature3 plugin.

Comment: Thank you!...it is not the solution, but is good start.